How to convert the data without collecting the flow?
I'm trying to convert the data I read from a repo class inside a ViewModel like this:
val itemFlow = flow {
    repo.getItemList().collect { itemList ->
        val itemListResult = try {
            Result.Success(itemList)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.Failure(e)
        }
        emit(itemListResult)
    }
}

My Result class looks like this:
sealed class Result<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Failure(val e: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}

And here is how I read the data from Room in the repo class:
override fun getItemList() = itemDao.getItemList()

Is there any way I can transform the itemList into an object of type Result.Success and Result.Failure without collecting the data?

Your implementation of try-catch is incorrect as it will not be able to catch any error from the getItemList method. As long as you don't call terminal operators like collect or launchIn your flow will remain cold. You can try the following:
val itemFlow = repo.getItemList()
    .map { Result.Success(it) } 
    .catch { e -> Result.Failure(e) }


Just to make it clear, this will now catch all errors occurring in getItemList() and Result.Success() whereas the code from the question only caught the latter. That may or may not have been on purpose. I would prefer to catch all errors in the flow chain, though, i.e. use the code as shown in this answer.

Although unrelated to the issue: Since this code is located in the view model and itemFlow is public: View model's should only expose StateFlows, so you might want to add stateIn() at the end.

@tyg To which answer are you referring to in your first comment? Maybe you can also post an answer on how to catch all errors in the flow chain and only expose StateFlow. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

What remains unclear when I say "I would prefer to catch all errors in the flow chain, though, i.e. use the code as shown in this answer."? It explicitly addresses this answer. -- And with "add stateIn() at the end" I meant the end of the chain. Since there is not other "end", that should have been quite obvious. Just try it out. If you cannot get it work you can ask a new question focusing on that.

@AlwaysLearner I don't think wrapping the value in Result object is going to throw any error so I didn't put it in try-catch. Also regadring StateFlow conversion you can check out a full example here: https://github.com/atick-faisal/Jetpack-Compose-Starter/blob/main/app/src/main/kotlin/dev/atick/compose/ui/home/HomeViewModel.kt

Thank you for the last comment. I'm looking forward to seeing @tyg approach and I will accept the best answer for me right away.

I think everything has been said. I have nothing substantial to add, so I won't write my own answer. This one is sufficient.

Yes, You can use "map" operator from koltin API to transform the emitted data from the repository into Result type without collecting the flow.
Please try below code
val itemFlow: Flow<Result<List<Item>>> = repo.getItemList()
    .map { itemList ->
        try {
            Result.Success(itemList)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.Failure(e)
        }
    }

You can transform the flow data using the map operator,
which allow  converting each emitted itemList into Result.Success or Result.Failure without collecting the flow.
This approach keeps the flow lazy and handles errors during the transformation seamlessly
